# Why is the accept / utility of one of my miners consistently higher than the others?

Tags: mining-hardware, bfgminer

I'm playing around with a couple of Antminer U2s, and two Block Erupters, running them off of a vanilla BFG setup using BTCGuild, I'm consistently seeing the following:

[image]

So, I'm curious as to why one of my miners (always a single AMU) always has such a higher Accept and Utility statistic than the other devices.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the worker with the more shares/utility is solving low difficulty pool shares, where the other 3 are probably mining at a more appropriate difficulty level.

Utility is the measure of how many shares are submitted per minute (diff1*pool difficulty mining at). That suggests further that the unit is working on lower difficulty shares than the other workers.

Usually on your pool website there will be a spot to change worker difficulty, and for those units, I would recommend 2 for the ICA and 8 for AMU, but you could always adjust according to your preference.